# "Wandering" Whine in Converted VHS tapes

Tags: filters, audio

I am attempting to clean up the audio from several VHS tapes that were dubbed to DVDs and then ripped. My tool of choice has been audacity, but I am open to other options. I have two questions:

1. In some of the tapes, there is a "whine" at ~2770 Hz, again at about twice that, and again at ~3 times that (not shown in spectrogram). These I can remove with notch filters, but I am curious about their source. The exact frequency of this peak varies slightly from tape to tape, but it is consistent within a tape.
2. There is also a second type of whine that typically starts ~7k and gradually "droops" as the video goes on. I have been removing this with a lo-pass filter, but I want to know if there is a better way.

[image: Spectrogram showing various artifacts.]